# "errorMessage":"Cannot find package 'axios' imported from /var/task/app.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have installed the dependency package for my lambada function using the Node.js 18 runtime, but I am receiving a module error. Alternatively, I can locate the package in the AWS lambada function.
I am using a sam lambada function
Error:-
PS C:\workspace\projects\demo api\node18> sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction
Invoking app.lambdaHandler (nodejs18.x)
Local image is up-to-date
Using local image: public.ecr.aws/lambda/nodejs:18-rapid-x86_64.

Mounting C:\workspace\projects\demo api\node18\hello-world as /var/task:ro,delegated, inside runtime container
START RequestId: 2dec49cf-7f7c-46d8-bf76-1684903c5ccd Version: $LATEST
2024-03-20T18:04:12.375Z        undefined       ERROR   Uncaught Exception      {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot find package 'axios' imported from /var/task/app.mjs","code":"ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND","stack":["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'axios' imported from /var/task/app.mjs","    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)","    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)","    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)","    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)","    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)","    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)","    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)","    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)","    at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)","    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}
20 Mar 2024 18:04:12,387 [ERROR] (rapid) Init failed InvokeID= error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129
20 Mar 2024 18:04:12,388 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke failed error=Runtime exited with error: exit status 129 InvokeID=d74cb566-34b2-40a2-8076-a6d5efb9688d
20 Mar 2024 18:04:12,388 [ERROR] (rapid) Invoke DONE failed: Sandbox.Failure
{"errorType": "Error", "errorMessage": "Cannot find package 'axios' imported from /var/task/app.mjs", "trace": ["Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'axios' imported from /var/task/app.mjs", "    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)", "    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:965:9)", "    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1022:20)", "    at moduleResolveWithNodePath (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:876:12)", "    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1242:79)", "    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:403:12)", "    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:372:25)", "    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:249:38)", "    at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:39)", "    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36)"]}

File structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQBXO.png)
[enter image description here]
It should run the sam lambada function through the nodejs18 in runtime